# How to return a sorted list's index in Perl?

Tags: perl

Say, I have a list:

```
@abc = (5,7,6,2,7,1);
```

I have to obtain a sorted list as well as a sorted list index. So the output will be:

```
@sorted_list = (7,7,6,5,2,1);
@sorted_list_index = (1,4,2,0,3,5);
```

I am also looking a very efficient approach for this problem, since I am actually dealing with a long list with 2^16 entries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to sort the indexes, you'll need to generate them

```
0..$#unsorted
```

Then you sort them like anything else

```
my @sorted_indexes = sort { $unsorted[$b] <=> $unsorted[$a] } 0..$#unsorted;
```

Grabbing the sorted values can be done using a slice.

```
my @sorted_values = @unsorted[ @sorted_indexes ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @abc = (5,7,6,2,7,1);
my $i = 0;

#Create an array of hashes (with value and index)
my @temp_abc = map { {value=>$_, index=>$i++} } @abc;

#Sort by the value of each hash
my @sorted_temp_abc = sort { $b->{value} <=> $a->{value} } @temp_abc; 

#extract the values to array @sorted_list
my @sorted_list = map { $_->{value} } @sorted_temp_abc;

#extract the values to array @sorted_list_index
my @sorted_list_index = map { $_->{index} } @sorted_temp_abc;

print "@sorted_list\n";        #<-- prints: 7 7 6 5 2 1
print "@sorted_list_index\n";  #<-- prints: 1 4 2 0 3 5
```

Comment: is your method faster than ikegami's method ?

Comment: @Chinegro No, on the contrary. He just wrote an explicit *Schwartzian Transform*.

Comment: If you look, you'll see that his code includes all of mine. His is obviously going to be slower. Even his sort expression is more expensive (11 ops to 7, a hash lookup instead of an array lookup). To put some numbers to that: In addition to calling 192K more code blocks then I do, he creates 64K more hashes, 64K more references and 64K more numbers than I do. All that time spent allocating and deallocating memory and storing values adds up.