# sorting two arrays simultaneously in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have two arrays.

```
1. @store_chromosomes( This is an array of arrays)
2. @fitness_values of the same length.

@store_chromosomes = ( ("attr1", "attr2", "attr3"), ("attr4", "attr5", "attr6"),  ("attr_m", "attr_n", "attr_o")); #Just an example
@fitness_values=(-0.3456, -0.6789, 0.5678); #just an example
```

Elements in `@fitness_values` corresponding to elements in `@store_chromosomes`, i.e., `-0.3456` is generated for `("attr1", "attr2", "attr3")` attribute and so on.

I need to arrange the elements in `@fitness_values` in descending order, i.e., `(-0.6789, -0.3456, 0.5678)` at the same time I need to arrange the elements of `@store_chromosomes` corresponding to the order of `@fitness_values`, i.e., `(("attr4", "attr5", "attr6"), ("attr1", "attr2", "attr3"), ("attr_m", "attr_n", "attr_o") )`.

For `@fitness_values`, I can do it by `@fitness_values = sort{4b<=>$a} @fitness_values`. But how to do it simultaneously for the array `@store_chromosomes`.

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124792/how-to-return-a-sorted-lists-index-in-perl). Sort the array and get the index then arrange the other array item with sorted index.

Comment: Or create hash like , first array elements as a key and second array values as a values. Then sort it by a keys

Comment: @mkHun Thank you so much for your reply. I feel, creating the hash is the best choice.

Comment: Perhaps it is just sloppy typing, but `(('a1', 'a2'), ('b1', 'b2'))` is _not_ a list with two elements being lists; it all gets flattened and it is just one list, `('a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2')`.  For what you show  you need arrayrefs as elements, `( ['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'] )`.